# Return True if string can be converted into float

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, input

I want my program to

- ask the user to enter a string text.
- print True if the string contains a valid float number, and can be safely be converted to a float using the float function.
- print False otherwise, i.e., if the string does not contains a valid float number, and float(text) produces an error message.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
`text = input("enter a string: ")`
 text = text.strip()
 float_check = float()

 for char in text:
      if text == float_check:
          print("true")
          break
      else:
          print("False")
          break
```

Comment: Why not just try to convert it?

Comment: I wanted it to print("true"), not return True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def is_float(string):
    try:
        float(string)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

and then to answer the question:

```
print(is_float(text))
```

Comment: I wanted it to print("true"), not return True

Comment: Edited the answer. Note though that it fixes an inconsistency in your print statements (true is not capitalized, while false is, not sure this is a typo or not)